# Passing information from a while loop to a bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I've currently got a while loop that echos all the information in my database onto a table. In this table there is a button that can be clicked to link to a modal.

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" class="active"><img src="img here"></a>
```

This then links to a modal with the code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <?php echo $row['name']; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is print out some of that information from the while loop into that modal `e.g.($row['name'])`. How can I do this? Can this be done through `PHP` or does it have to be `JS`?

Comment: Show what have you done so far. `JS` codes I mean

Comment: I haven't got any JS code so far, I've uploaded the modal I'm using if that helps.

Comment: Can you provide an example that show what you expect? (I mean from other sites or simplified case)